# Gerschgorin's Disks of a 3x3 complex matrix

Tags: matrices

How to estimate the radii of Gerschgorin's Disks from a 3x3 square complex matrix? Is the disks just simply center at the diagonal elements with radius equal to the sum of the absolute values of other elements of the same row?

Comment: Yes.$\;\;\;\;\;$